# Why react native material FAB does not work?

Tags: react-native, material-design

I tried to find solution everywhere but still stuck on this issue.
I'm trying to implement `<FAB />` from `react-native-material` but got this issue:
[ISSUE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcxTD.png)

*ps. I don't use react native expo*

My code:

```
import React from "react";
import { Stack, FAB } from "@react-native-material/core";
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons";

const MyFAB = () => (
    <Stack fill center>
        <FAB icon={props => <Icon name="star" {...props} />} color="primary" />
    </Stack>
);

export default MyFAB;
```

Comment: Are you sure error is received after adding FAB? Can you add version of react native and material version?

Comment: `react-native: 0.69.1 => 0.69.1`
`"@react-native-material/core": "^1.3.7"`

Error is received after FAB added, If I comment it, then error disappear